# How to make my program show a form on first launch

Tags: vb.net

What i mean by this question is for the very first time its opened. Say Monday I installed and opened this program then i want it to show a form, then let them use the program then say they open on Tuesday or whenever they never get that form to show again.

Comment: You want to say, that specific form will be opened only first time after installation and never ever again?

Comment: Just create an [Appication Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet) of type Boolean and check that when your app opens.  If you want it to appear before your "Startup Object" (main form, usually) then use the [Application Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup?view=netframework-4.7) event.

Comment: @nelek yes dude you know how?

Comment: @BrandonWilliams like @Idle_Mind wrote... but, maybe, better set `Sub Main()` for startup application (create one module with `Sub Main()...End Sub`, in `Project/Properties` under `Application` uncheck `Enable application framework` and from dropdown `Starup object:` choose `Sub Main`) from where You'll check is that first time start... and, maybe, better idea to store that value in registry... check is any data about your app stored in registry, if not - start one form, if data is in registry start another one.